# AWS Batch vs AWS Step functions for Control M migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-batch, control-m

The goal is to migrate our jobs from Control M to AWS, but before I do that I want to better understand the differences between AWS batch and AWS step functions. From what I've understood, AWS step functions seems more encompassing in that I can have one of my steps run AWS batch.

Can you explain the difference between AWS Batch and AWS Step functions? Which is better suited to migrate to from Control M? (Maybe this is preference)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AWS Batch is service to run an offline workload. With Batch, you can easily set up your offline workload using Docker and defining the set of instances types and how many instances will run this workload.

AWS Step Functions is a serverless workflow management service. It only serves you a way to connect to other AWS Services; you cannot run a script in Step Functions itself and you only define the workflow with input/output from other AWS services.

[image]

That said, you can use both services to migrate Control M to AWS and possibly other AWS Services like Lambda (for minor workload), SNS (for e-mail) and S3 (for storage).

Comment: `It only serves you a way to connect to other AWS Services; you cannot run a script in Step Functions itself and you only define the workflow with input/output from other AWS services.` This clears pretty much everything up. Thanks!